# Change font styles or highlight dataset entries depending on value in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a webpage running on ASP.NET which sends SQL select statements to gather and populate a dataset on the client side. When the webpage is loaded, each datarow of the dataset is traversed and displayed onto a table in the webpage. I would like to have certain columns checked such that some rows would be highlighted (or style color changed at least) if they contained null in any of its entries. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to check whether the columns are empty on not.And can give specific colours or effects to that rows.as you have not given an html sample i cant give you a sample code.Thinks this will help you to solve your problem.